# AJAX call with Spring Boot and UTF 8 deciding prevention

Tags: javascript, java

When I send a string `'This is a box'` through Java AJAX call in a JSON string, but in server side I got `'This%20is%20a%20box'` . How I can prevent this conversation?  When I see the Dev tool of browser then in request pay load I got converted string only.

I am using Spring Boot, and JavaScript AJAXs, and I am setting content type as `application/json;charcet=utf-8` while sending only it got converted .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to tell how you are doing the submission and receiving the response with the lack of code in your question.

However, it appears that you are submitting the text box as part of a form based on the `This%20is%20a%20box` value being form encoded.  In which case you should not be receiving `application/json` content type in your Spring Boot application, but rather `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If you are intending to send json data to the service then you need to send json data and not submit the form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#your-form").submit(function (event) {

        //stop form submission, send manually
        event.preventDefault();

        do_ajax_submit();

    });

});

function do_ajax_submit() {

    var val = //Get the value here

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/api/endpoint",
        data: JSON.stringify(val),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
           // Do something
        },
        error: function (e) {
           // Do something
        }
    });

}
```